# How to Binary Serializer Custom Class

Tags: c#, serialization, binary, deserialization, binaryfiles

I've this custom class:

```
public class MyClass
{ 
    private byte byteValue;
    private int intValue;
    private MyClass myClass1= null;
    private MyClass myClass2 = null;
}
```

obviously I also have constructor and get/set methods.

In my main form I initialize a lot of `MyClass` object (note that in `MyClass` object I have reference to other 2 MyClass objects). After initialization I iterate through a first `MyClass` item, call it for instance "root". So, for example I do something like:

```
MyClass myClassTest = root.getMyClass1();
MyClass myClassTest2 = myClassTest.getMyClass1();
```

and so on.

No I want to store in a binary file, all the `MyClass` object instantiated, in order to get them again after software restart.

I have totally no idea on how to do this, can someone please help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Here is a related question and answer that might give you some ideas. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933187/is-implementing-iserializable-interface-necessary-when-not-implementing-any-cust

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First add the attribute [Serializable] before the class declaration. More about the attributes go to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw.aspx

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass
{ 
    private byte byteValue;
    private int intValue;
    private MyClass myClass1= null;
    private MyClass myClass2 = null;
}
```

Note: all the class members must be also serializable.
For serializing the object to binary you can use the following code sample:

```
using (Stream stream = File.Open(serializationPath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            var binaryFormatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
            binaryFormatter.Serialize(stream, objectToSerialize);
            stream.Close();
        }
```

And for the deserializing from binary:

```
using (Stream stream = File.Open(serializationFile, FileMode.Open))
        {
            var binaryFormatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();

            deserializedObject = (MyClass)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }
```

Comment: If I use private class member, serialize doesn't works, but thanks.

Comment: I just wrote a sample program and tested it, in my code it is working fine with private members (serializing and deserializing). I think the private members will be problem with XmlSerialization not with Binary.

Comment: Yes, private fields are serialized by BinaryFormatter.