# Serializing a custom class to a file

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I'm writing a save method for my `Player` class, I can serialize most fields using a binary writer however my custom class fields are not able to be serialized (i have a Race field for custom races)

Since I am going to have a lot of different custom classes - like Race - I really need a good reliable way of saving this information.

So, am I using the wrong kind of formatter? And if so, what is the one I should be using?
Alternatively, how do I write the method to serialize it? I have used the `[Serializable()]` attribute and implemented `ISerializable` interface where needed already.

Here is the code:

```
public void Save()
{
    Stream stream = File.Open(SaveSlot, FileMode.Create);
    BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);
    PlayerData saveData = new PlayerData();

    writer.Write(saveData.Name = PlayerData.player.Name);
    writer.Write(saveData.Race = PlayerData.player.Race);
    writer.Write(saveData.PlayClass = PlayerData.player.PlayClass);
    writer.Write(saveData.Level = PlayerData.player.Level);
    writer.Write(saveData.Experience = PlayerData.player.Experience);
    writer.Write(saveData.Strength = PlayerData.player.Strength);
    writer.Write(saveData.Dexterity = PlayerData.player.Dexterity);
    writer.Write(saveData.Constitution = PlayerData.player.Constitution);
    writer.Write(saveData.Intelligence = PlayerData.player.Intelligence);
    writer.Write(saveData.Wisdom = PlayerData.player.Wisdom);
    writer.Write(saveData.Charisma = PlayerData.player.Charisma);
    writer.Write(saveData.Wounds = PlayerData.player.Wounds);
    writer.Write(saveData.MaxWounds = PlayerData.player.MaxWounds);
    writer.Write(saveData.Attackbonus = PlayerData.player.Attackbonus);
    writer.Write(saveData.Defensebonus = PlayerData.player.Defensebonus);

    writer.Close();
    Console.WriteLine("Data Saved Successfully");
}
```

Comment: Have you thought about using a json format instead? You could do this in one line using newtonsoft for example.

Comment: no i didnt even know that was an option.

how clean would it be to impliment? (i have a lot of code scattered around trying to make this work)

Comment: This is how you serialize a custom class: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30920669/711061

Comment: @MightyBadaboom Switching to json format is not required to achieve serialization nor to serialize in a single line of code. Don't force that into OP. just help him with his problem.

Answer (score 2):

Like I said in my comment you can use the json format for this.

**Sample class**

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

**Sample data**

```
List<MyObject> objects = new List<MyObject>
{
    new MyObject{MyProperty = "test 1"},
    new MyObject{MyProperty = "test 2"},
    new MyObject{MyProperty = "test 3"}
};
```

**Sample code**

Then you can use this code for serialize your data (using [Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)).

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objects);
```

The content of `json` will be

> [{"MyProperty":"test 1"},{"MyProperty":"test 2"},{"MyProperty":"test
>   3"}]

If you want to deserialize the string use this.

```
List<MyObject> deserialzed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyObject>>(json);
```

**More info**

You can save the json string to a file and load and deserialize it when you need it. This works with every type of a property including list and custom objects.

Have a read at the [JSON format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) for more information.

Comment: cool, can it convert anything? so for example my custom race classes have things like name and description strings, type and size enums, and a variety of ints.

if i did something like Basehuman json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(player.Race) 

would it do all the conversions no problem?

Comment: @RichardLester Short answer: Yes, you can :)

Comment: @RichardLester If you want to check if everything worked use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objects, Formatting.Indented)` and you get a formatted `string` instead of a "one liner". That's easier to read for humans :)

Comment: i plan to make a variety of dictionaries to hold instances of all my "standardised" stuff, things that will never really change and merely needs a reference, so things like the race field will eventually have pointers to those entries if that changes anything

Comment: as far as readability i'm not bothered as long as i can save the data to a file

Comment: @RichardLester As far as I can say without knowing your structure it should not be a problem because dictionaries aren't a problem at all for json.

Comment: Cool, im gonna get started and make these dictionaries and have a go at chanigng my save/load class to a json style save/load

Comment: okay so i have done the database which solved a few inefficiencies i was having, so how/what do i do to serialize playerdata and then save it to file using the json/newtonsoft approach?

Comment: @RichardLester Just use the same synatx: `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(playerdata);` and the `FIle.WriteAllText`method to save your string.