# How to convert Dictionary into Binary Serialize in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, serialization

i have the following code convert Dictionary into Binary Serialize

```
private IDictionary<string, ConnectionManager> dictionary = new SortedDictionary<string, ConnectionManager>();
ConnectionManager conn;
dictionary.Add("testid", conn = new ConnectionManager());
IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
Stream stream = new FileStream(@"c:\test1.txt",
FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
formatter.Serialize(stream, dictionary);
```

see the class code here in detail

```
ConnectionManager.cs
```

https://github.com/Sicos1977/MailKitImapIdler/tree/master/MailKitImapIdler

I have a problem to convert Dictionary into binary serialize.
I have the following error while pass dictionary into binary serializes.
I have already applied `[Serializeable]` tag on top of the `ConnectionManager` class

> {"Type 'System.Threading.AutoResetEvent' in Assembly 'mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is
>   not marked as serializable."}

[image]

please suggest me, how can I resolve my problem. I appreciate your valuable time. thanks.

Comment: Please provide an short and complete code how to reproduce this problem.

Comment: Try to add `NonSerialized` attribute to your `AutoResetEvent` member.

Comment: the ConnectionManagerIdle class has 1248 line of code. you can see the class here with name ConnectionManager.cs https://github.com/Sicos1977/MailKitImapIdler/tree/master/MailKitImapIdler

Comment: @DogeAmazed i have updated question with code as well,

Comment: @vasek can you explain how to use it. thanks

Comment: Well the question probably should be _Why are you trying to serialize `Connection` object?_ Your error comes from the fact that some member of the complex class contains `AutoResetEvent` which is obviously not serializable.

Comment: @john Why post it as an duplicate of an duplicate? Just use the original one.

Comment: @DogeAmazed did you understand my question or just wondering?

Comment: @adnan Serializing your connection manager makes no sense: most of your members are, for lack of a better word, _transient_ objects. The `Task` objects only have value while they're running in memory, you can't reload a `Stream` from a serialized file, `AutoResetEvent` is not meant to be serialized for similar reasons. What exactly are you trying to save? I think you're approaching your problem incorrectly. You should define the actual data you want to save and move that specific data to its own serializable class(es).

Comment: @ john yes, you are right at all, i appreciate you identified my problem, why i want to store connectionmanager, because i want to access later the objects in other class, e.g its start connection with email to idle state, and i want to stop from another class or outside of scope.

Comment: @adnan then you need to get only what you need from your ConnectionManager and/or respective Connection classes and serialize only those properties. I am talking about connection configuration - user name, password, host... and those are serializable very easily.

Comment: @vasek you are good, yes i required, what connection was started with what connection object. i am not sure what will be used for. e.g i start connection, 1 connection may have more than 1 email accounts for. if i can save connection and when i stop by those object, it should only stop those connection only. you may get more idea. thanks

Comment: Then you should create something like `ConnectionConfiguration` class with all required members (user name, password, etc.) and serialize array of these simple classes, which should be a trivial task. Then after your program starts again and you deserialize your array, you should use it for creating all `ConnectionManager` objects.

Comment: @vasek can you make little code example for. if possible. thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You should not make an attempt to serialize complex `ConnectionManager` class full of transient members, e.g. event handles. Yous should pick neccessary configuration members from respective `Connection` classes and serialize only those.

For example, your code might look like this:

```
[Serializable]
ConnectionConfiguration
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Host { get; set; }
    public int Port { get; set; }

    // some other members might follow here
}
```

And then you serialize and deserialize only array of these objects. You might also add some type property with POP3/IMAP account type.

Then after deserialization you just simply call `AddImapConnection` or `AddPop3Connection` on your empty `ConnectionManager` which provides neccessary initialization for the manager object.

Comment: can you explain, if we add ConnectionConfiguration object in dictionary, do we manage the connections there?

Comment: why would you use dictionary for managing configurations? Simple flat array is absolutely enough for you. If you need some naming, you just can simply add property `Name` and name your configuration for yourself.

Comment: @adnan That's a separate responsibility. Imagine the `ConnectionConfiguration` class like a cinema ticket: It has the screen number, the movie, the seat number, etc. Now, you don't use that to watch the film, but you give it to the staff members who direct you to the screen and your seat, and who play the movie.

The configuration class is the ticket, the connection manager is the cinema.

Comment: @vasek basically my end target is to store dictionary into physical file after converting binary serialize, but i have problem with binary serialize. later i want to access the same data to deserialize and use it.

Comment: @adnan And this "data" you want to store is the configuration data for your ConnectionManager, right? Things like server IP and credentials?

Comment: @adnan then you might be looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30918176/how-to-binary-serializer-custom-class).

Comment: @john and vasek, e.g when we call AddImapConnection by providing its credentials like username, pwd, hostname etc, then start ConnectionManager.Start(); its start the connection, we want to save this state in file, if i just save in dictionary at all, and then i can use by dictionary to ConnectionManager.Stop(); but i want the same by physical file, because dictionary is not available out of scope. all is working in system memory but we want to save in file, in general. thanks

Comment: What state are we talking about? Can you elaborate more on this and name connection properties you want to save? Please note you can never restore *original state* of complex objects that have a lot of transient states.

Comment: in general idea, if there 1000 email accounts we are login by the connection manager, each email account started by different connection object, application is running fine, but how to stop each of the email account connection by their specified connection object. normally we can do by using dictionary, but we do not have any way to store in DB or file, like dictionary save.

Comment: I am not sure if I get your point. Do you want to enable and disable mailbox polling for respective connection during runtime?

Comment: I see. There is no support for such a functionality. You have to create a new property in `Connection` class, e.g. `IsEnabled` of type bool and modify `ConnectionWorker` in `ConnectionManager` so that you don't poll connections that are disabled. Come on man, this is very simple task!